# How can i override a default variable from CMakeLists.txt on CMake command line?

Tags: cmake

I have a .cmake file containing default values for variables. The .cmake file is called from CMakeLists.txt using 'include'.
One of the variables is a version number.
What is the best practice or setup to overrule that variable version number from CMake command line?

In gnu make you could use 
var ?= value 
where you can set var value on make command line. I do not see something similar in C-Make.

Answer (score 1):

For boolean values, you can use `option`:

```
option(CUSTOMIZABLE_VAR "This variable do stuff" "default-value")
```

Also GUI apps exposing options such as CMake GUI or QtCreator you'll get a the description and a field to edit it.

For value of type string, you can set a cache value with a help string:

```
set(CUSTOMIZABLE_VAR "8" CACHE STRING "This option is a string")
```

Comment: By specifying ..."5" default value in option line, then calling
CMake -DCUSTOMIZABLE_VAR=6,  the variable gets value 6. That is ok.
When not specifying -DCUSTOMIZABLE_VAR in CMake command line, the variable has value "OFF", not "5".

Comment: @BaudewijnVermeire oups sorry, I misread the docs. option is for boolean values. Otherwise you can use a cache variable. I updated the answer